# Why my powershell script return wrong exit code?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I'm trying to return exit code from a powershell script that is executed on a remote machine. But, when I check `ExitCode` it has some random number.

What I'm doing wrong? In addition, is it possible to return the whole text?

**my script**

```
$proc = Start-Process -Filepath "$PSExec" -ArgumentList "\\$server -h -u $user -p $pass -d PowerShell $command" -PassThru -Wait
$proc.ExitCode
```

**remote script**

```
New-Item "c:\temp\1.txt" -type file -force
exit 123
```

**UPDATE**

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -Force -AsPlainText #$password includes password in clear text
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($usrName, $secureString)  
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred
$command = "`"C:\temp\1.ps1`""
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock { 
    Start-Process -Filepath "$PSExec" -ArgumentList "\\$server -h -u $usrName -p $password -d PowerShell $command" -PassThru -Wait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `Invoke-Command` as an alternative?

Example:

```
$session = New-PSSesson -ComputerName $serverName -Credential (Get-Credential)
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
    Start-Process ...
}
```

As an alternative to `Get-Credential` you can created a credential object and pass it via the `-Credential` paramter to `Invoke-Command`. Example:

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -Force -AsPlainText #$password includes password in clear text
$cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($usrName, $secureString)  
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock { ... }
```

`$result` should also include the `ExitCode` property, since Powershell Remoting serializes the remote object. I always suggest Powershell Remoting compared to the cmdlet specific `ComputerName` implementations. It uses a more standardized way (WsMan -> HTTP(S)). See this [link](http://techgenix.com/remote-management-powershell-part1/) for further details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @when I run `$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential (Get-Credential)` it opens a popup window to enter username and password. How I can pass username and password in script?

Comment: It throws `Logon failure` exception on `New-PSSession`. I know that username and password are correct since `PSExec` does success to access the server. I've added an update to my post with the code. Thanks

Comment: Can it be something with my password. My password is `$password="$mypass!"`. It's not shown here, but I use "`" character to before "$" to escape it the "$" sign. Is it correct?

Comment: when using double quotes PowerShell tries to replace variables inside the string, which is the case in your example. Try to write your password in single quotes -> `$password='$mypass!'. When using single quotes PowerShell will store the string as it is. Example: Write-Host '$hello`!$%'

Comment: I tried it and it still gives me the same error `[server1] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
`

Comment: My host and remote machines are Win7. I enabled `WS-Management` service in both of them. Do I need to enable something else?

Comment: What Powershell version do you use? Type `$PSVersionTable`. Here is a link desribing what you've to do to enable PS remoting: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

For your first approach, your issue is that when running `psexec` with the `-d` (don't wait) flag it returns the pid of the command that launched it, rather than waiting and returning the exitcode.

Altogether your process also could be optimized. First if you wanted to use `psexec.exe`, I don't see a reason for `Start-Process` since you are waiting and passing through. Just `& $psexec ...` would suffice.

However Moerwald's suggestion for using `Invoke-Command` is a great one. In your updated code, you are still running `Start-Process` and `Psexec` which are unnecessary. When you are invoking the command, you are already remotely running code, so just run the code:

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -Force -AsPlainText 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($usrName, $secureString)  
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
    New-Item "c:\temp\1.txt" -type file -force
    exit 123
}
```

Also, since it doesn't look like you are reusing the session, I dropped the saving the session to a variable. And it would also be better to replace all of the credential setup with a Get-Credential rather than passing plaintext passwords around (avoid the password ending up in a saved transcript). That would look like this:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock { 
    New-Item "c:\temp\1.txt" -type file -force
    exit 123
}
```

Comment: but your last code will popup the credentials window to enter username and password

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to run powershell script on the remote machine. For that I need first to enable `ExecutionPolicy` on the remote machine. I do NOT want to do it manually, but EVERYTHING remotely. I have VPN to the remote machine. So, what I did is I copy a batch file to the remote machine which adds a registry with `ExecutionPolicy=RemoteSigned`. I want to exectute that batch file with `PsExec` and then I'll be able to run powershell script on that remote machine. `Invoke-Command` requires me to configure all my remote servers. With `PsExec` I don't have to configure anything.

Comment: In any case, I removed `-d` but I still don't get the exit code. Can you please post the working example?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: If you are setting Execution Policy then best practice would be to set it through Group Policy: Computer/Adm Templates/Windows Components/Windows PowerShell/Turn on Script Execution